Polynomial long division with macro command in a for loop (to get different coefficients)
I would like to create problem sheets with polynomial long division, where each student gets different polynomials. I tried to use the polynom package, but the following code does not compile (it does not terminate!). How should I patch this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, polynom}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5 + 1 * x}{x^2 - 7x + 1} %this works fine
\vspace{5cm}

\foreach \a in {1, ..., 5} {
    \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5 + \a * x}{x^2 - 7x + \a}\\ 
    %An infinite loop seems to occur. NB: \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5 + \a * x}{x^2 - 7x + 1} does compile but gives strange results.
    \vspace*{5cm}
}
\end{document}


I used to do this by combining C++ and LaTeX (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/polydiv.pdf)

Thanks to the other answer, I came up with the following code, which completely solves my problem!
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{roboto}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{intcalc, mathtools, ifthen}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\print}{m O{}}{%
    \ifnum #1 < -1
        #1          #2
    \fi
    \ifnum #1 = 1
        #2
    \fi
    \ifnum #1 = -1
        - #2
    \fi
    \ifnum #1 > 0
        + #1        #2
    \else
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719607
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{6}} \do {
    \def\RacineA{\the\numexpr   \intcalcMod{2*#1}{6} + 1\relax}
    \def\RacineB{\the\numexpr   -\intcalcMod{#1 - 1}{6} - 1  \relax}
    \def\CoefC{\the\numexpr     -\intcalcMod{#1}{5} - 5  \relax}
    \def\CoefD{\the\numexpr     \intcalcMod{#1}{5} + 1  \relax}
        %SAGEMATH :
    %R.<RacineA,RacineB,CoefC,CoefD> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
    %S.<x> = PolynomialRing(R)
    %P = (x-RacineA)*(x-RacineB)*(x^2 + CoefC*x + CoefD)
    %P.coefficients()
    
    \def\CoefK{\the\numexpr  -\RacineA - \RacineB + \CoefC  \relax}
    \def\CoefL{\the\numexpr\RacineA*\RacineB - \RacineA*\CoefC - \RacineB*\CoefC + \CoefD \relax}
    \def\CoefM{\the\numexpr\RacineA*\RacineB*\CoefC - \RacineA*\CoefD - \RacineB*\CoefD \relax}
    \def\CoefN{\the\numexpr \RacineA*\RacineB*\CoefD + #1 \relax}
    
    \def\discr{\fpeval{(\CoefC)^2 - 4*\CoefD}}
    
    \xintFor* #2 in {\xintSeq{\CoefK}{\CoefK}} \do {
    \xintFor* #3 in {\xintSeq{\CoefL}{\CoefL}} \do {
    \xintFor* #4 in {\xintSeq{\CoefM}{\CoefM}} \do {
    \xintFor* #5 in {\xintSeq{\CoefN - #1}{\CoefN - #1}} \do {  
    \xintFor* #6 in {\xintSeq{-\RacineA - \RacineB}{-\RacineA - \RacineB}} \do {    
    \xintFor* #7 in {\xintSeq{\RacineA * \RacineB}{\RacineA * \RacineB}} \do {  
        Find all solutions of the following equation, knowing that  $x = \RacineA$ and $x = \RacineB$ are two solutions~:
        \begin{align*}
        x^4  
        \print{\CoefK}[x^3]
        \print{\CoefL}[x^2]
        \print{\CoefM}[x]
        \print{\CoefN}
        =
        #1
        \end{align*}
        
        \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^4 + #2 * x^3 + #3 * x^2 + #4 * x + #5}{x^2 + #6 * x + #7}
    }}}}}}
    \newpage
}
\end{document}


The problem is, that \a doesn't expand correctly in this context. How to make it to do so, I have no idea ... but this answer uses a different approach via xinttools:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools, polynom}
\begin{document}
\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5 + 1 * x}{x^2 - 7x + 1} %this works fine
\vspace{5cm}


\xintFor #1 in {1,2,3,4,5}\do
{#1:
    \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5 + #1 * x}{x^2 - 7x + #1}\\ 
    \vspace*{5cm}
}

\end{document}

P.S.: To specify a range, use the stared version * together with \xintSeq[]{}{}:
...
%\xintFor #1 in {1,2,3,4,5}\do
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{4}}\do
{#1:
...


Thanks a lot! Do you know how to proceed to have something like \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5 + #1 * x}{x^2 - 7x + #2} where   #2 = 2*#1 + 3 ? That is, I want to define a second parameter which depends on the first one. I get an issue if #2 consists of more than 2 symbols (e.g. #2 equals 11).

OK, I found a (possibly ugly) way, which I share in my answer below.
